# Android studio adding admob in java class

Tags: java, android-sdk, android-studio, admob

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container,false);
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Hi does anyone knows why system can find findViewbyId? Thanks
Здраствуйте.Кто-нибудь осведомлён почему не показывает findViewbyId?Спасибо

error:

```
Error:(24, 28) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
C:\Users\AVE-RAIN\AndroidStudioProjects\southkorea\app\src\main\java\com\ave_rain\southkorea\FragmentOne.java
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: translate to russian please or use stackoverflow.com

Comment: после оператора `return` код вообще не выполняется, потому что происходит выход из метода.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. После вызова return выполнение кода прекращается.
2. Вы должны искать mAdView в загружаемой разметке фрагмента, а не в классе фрагмента. Класс `Fragment` не имеет метода `findViewById`

   ```
   public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{
       private AdView mAdView;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container,false);
           mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
           AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
           mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
           return v;
       }
   }
   ```